# Does Pharah's Concussive Blast wake sleeping enemies?

Tags: overwatch

If an enemy has been hit with Ana's sleeping dart and is sleeping, will they wake from a hit caused by Concussive Blast?

The Concussive Blast does 0 damage but it does cause damage indication even when you use it for a rocket jump, so does it count?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope.  Sleeping enemies will continue sleeping for whatever duration is left from the dart.

The attack has to deal damage to wake the opponent up.

Comment: You able to link a source for that? Not doubting, this lines up with my personal experience too (knocking sleeping Roadhogs off cliffs), but a source would be super useful :)

Comment: @KizTrap According to [the Overrwatch Wikia](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Sleep_Dart), while not the greatest source, claims that an enemy must take damage to wake up. Considering Phara's concussive blast does no damage, it would not wake up a sleeping enemy.

Comment: Good enough for me :) Easy to test anyways..